# Is this the correct way of compositing volumetrics?

Tags: compositing-nodes, volumetrics

The Blender documentation shows a neat diagram of how to composite the different render passes together in the compositor (bottom of page): https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html

But it doesn't mention volumetrics.

Is this the correct way of compositing them?
[image]

Comment: Yes is an addition as the diffuse and glossy, but you should put the volume after your sky (before your exposure)

Comment: Thanks @Emir ! That's a good point to remember in the future. In this specific case the sky-image was just some cosmetic stars I wanted to mix in with the HDRI so it was not vital nor desirable to have the volume affect it. Next time it might though.